# how to join multiple csv files without repetition?

Tags: python, csv

I have 3 csv files they all should have the same date column like that:

```
file1.csv             file2.csv             file3.csv
date,price1           date,price2           date,price3
2017-03-03,1900       2017-03-03,1200       2017-03-03,1220
2017-03-04,2900       2017-03-04,2200       2017-03-04,2233
2017-03-04,1300       2017-03-04,1549       2017-03-04,1520
```

I want to join them and get this using python:

```
file4.csv
date,price1,price2,price3
2017-03-03,1900,1200,1220
2017-03-04,2900,2200,2233
2017-03-04,1300,1549,1520
```

Comment: What is your approach till now? Are you getting any specific error or problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one can combine two files at a time.  Repeat the process for other files as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('file3.csv')

df12 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on='date')
df123 = pd.merge(df12, df3, how='outer', on='date')
print(df123)
```

Comment: Thank you it is simple and it works.